# How to compute the number of weights of a CNN?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, keras, filters, convolution-arithmetic

How can we theoretically compute the number of weights considering a convolutional neural network that is used to classify images into two classes:

- INPUT: 100x100 gray-scale images.
- LAYER 1: Convolutional layer with 60 7x7 convolutional filters (stride=1, valid
  padding).
- LAYER 2: Convolutional layer with 100 5x5 convolutional filters (stride=1, valid
  padding).
- LAYER 3: A max pooling layer that down-samples Layer 2 by a factor of 4 (e.g., from 500x500 to 250x250)
- LAYER 4: Dense layer with 250 units
- LAYER 5: Dense layer with 200 units
- LAYER 6: Single output unit

Assume the existence of biases in each layer. Moreover, the pooling layer has a weight (similar to AlexNet)

How many weights does this network have?

Here would be the corresponding model in Keras, but note that I am asking for how to calculate this with a formula, not in Keras.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(60, (7, 7), input_shape = (100, 100, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")) # Layer 1
model.add(Conv2D(100, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu")) # Layer 2
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) # Layer 3
model.add(Dense(250)) # Layer 4
model.add(Dense(200)) # Layer 5

model.summary()
```

Comment: [Here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/18663/2444) is a related (if not duplicate) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the number of parameters in a CNN is very straightforward.

A CNN is composed of different **filters**, which are essentially 3d tensors. CNN weights are **shared**, meaning they are used multiple times and reused in different locations. Each layer has $n$ tensors, each with dimension $w \times h \times c$, where $w$ = width, $h$ = height, $c$ = channels (the input channel size). Therefore, the number of parameters of a convolutional layer is $w * h * c * n$. There is also a bias for each output channel, so the number of biases is $n$. At the end the parameter number is calculated with: $n * w * h * c + n$. See more about this in hear: [Article](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-and-calculating-the-number-of-parameters-in-convolution-neural-networks-cnns-fc88790d530d)

The pooling layer does not have weights, it only has **hyperparameters**. You may have confused the two. There are hyperparameters for the stride, the factor and etc. These are predefined and not trainable.

For Keras, you can use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35827171/4886927).